# How to use a php inside js

Tags: javascript, php

When i use the php and js separately it is working correctly

```
<script> var test = 'asdasdasd'; </script> <?php $id =
"<script>document.write(test)</script>"; echo $id; ?>
```

But when I use the php inside the js function it is not working correctly

```
<script>    var test = 'asdasdasd'; <?php $id =
"<script>document.write(test)</script>"; echo $id; ?> </script>
```

How can make work my second  code?

Comment: var test=<?php echo 'Master';?> ;   try it this way

Comment: These lines are identical, aren't they?

Comment: Nah.. In the second code the php is inside the js function

Comment: I fixed the formatting - some of the content was hidden by using quote rather than code block.

Answer (score 2):

The second code produces wrong HTML/JS:

```
<script>    var test = 'asdasdasd'; <script>document.write(test)</script> </script>
```

- see for yourself in the generated page.

Since everything between `<script>` and `</script>` is considered to be JS code, it will try to parse the inner `<script>` as Javascript code...and fail.

I think the inner other of `<script>...</script>` tags (those that are in PHP markup) is not needed at all, just get rid of them and it will work.

Comment: <script>

 var test = 'asdasdasd';
 

<?php
$id = "'+test+'" ;
echo $id;
//here i want to run sql code 
?>
</script>

Answer (score 1):

You can insert any value from php to absolutely everywhere in your file. Literally everywhere.
While writing client-side code, in the right place open php tag `<?php` and echo what you need. Don't forget to write a closing tag `?>` afterwards.

Here, you are echoing the opening `script` tag, which you already wrote before. That results in a syntax error:

```
<script>
<script>
...
</script>
```